# Creating a next feature without adding fields to a table?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a polling web application, which has a bunch of polls. There are two tables, one with poll question's and answers, and one with people's votes on those polls. For each user I want to provide next functionality, so that when they press a next button it will take them to a new poll that they have not answered. I don't want to add anymore fields to the table, and I am not sure how to "save" the poll id's for a specific user which have not been answered. This has definitely been done many times before, What are solutions/design patterns you have used?

Comment: YOu can query the db and see which questions they haven't answered and present one of those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a random poll user hasn't answered yet:

```
SELECT p.poll_id FROM polls p WHERE p.poll_id NOT IN
(SELECT r.poll_id FROM poll_to_user r WHERE r.user_id = [current_user_id])
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: It didn't occur to me that I could do this on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

You will just have to query for a poll id that you have no vote on from this user.

```
SELECT p.id 
FROM polls p
WHERE p.id NOT IN (SELECT v.poll_id FROM votes v WHERE v.user_id = $this_user_id)
ORDER BY p.date_added 
LIMIT 1;
```

or `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` if you prefer to get one at random.

If your table structure for `votes` does not store poll ID and user ID then there must be some other way to uniquely identify poll and user.

Comment: The SQL you provided would never return a poll that nobody has taken yet.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, Joshua. I should have put more thought into it. It should instead be looking in the polls table. I'll re-write.